# Qt3D render 32-bit colors instead of 24-bit

Tags: opengl, qt3d, pyside2

It is possible to render 32-bit colors in **Qt3D**?

```py
attr = Qt3DRender.QAttribute()
attr.setAttributeType(Qt3DRender.QAttribute.VertexAttribute)
attr.setBuffer(buffer)
attr.setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender.QAttribute.UnsignedByte)
attr.setVertexSize(4)  # 4 bytes instead of 3
attr.setByteOffset(0)
attr.setByteStride(4 * 1)  # 4 bytes instead of 3
attr.setCount(count)
attr.setName(Qt3DRender.QAttribute.defaultColorAttributeName())
```

The rendered colors are only 24-bit.

I need 32-bit color because I am working on a offscreen renderer (Thank you  @Florian Blume (https://github.com/Sonnentierchen/Qt3D-OffscreenRenderer)). I need this for point snapping. So far it works but only for 24-bit RGB colors.

```py
# Create a texture to render into.
self.texture = Qt3DRender.QTexture2D(self.output)
self.texture.setFormat(Qt3DRender.QAbstractTexture.RGBA8_UNorm)
self.texture.setMinificationFilter(Qt3DRender.QAbstractTexture.Nearest)
self.texture.setMagnificationFilter(Qt3DRender.QAbstractTexture.Nearest)
```

My shader:

```
float byte = 256.;
float f_index = float(gl_VertexID);
float remainder = f_index - (byte*byte * floor(f_index/(byte*byte)));
float r = (f_index - remainder) / (byte*byte);
float b = remainder - (byte * floor(remainder/byte));
float g = (remainder - b) / byte;

r = r / (byte - 1.);
g = g / (byte - 1.);
b = b / (byte - 1.);

color = vec4(b, g, r, 1.0);
```

Comment: What do you even _mean_ by 32 bit colors? And what has the vertex attribute setup to do with it?

Comment: I want to color points in a 3D space with distinct colors. If I use 24-bit colors, I can only draw `~16 × 10^6` points. But I want to show more points. `VertexAttribute` is used when setting a color.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? You know that normal computer screens can only display 24-bit colors? You need specialized displays to see deeper colors. If you want to be able to identify them by color you could use the alpha channel, as well. This would give you 32-bit. Points with 0 alpha would of course not be visible.

Comment: "The rendered colors are only 24-bit.": This can mean two things: you are looking at the shader output values directly, or you are looking at the actualy display on your monitor. You never show the shader, nor the setup for your render targets / window pixel formats. You show us the shader _input_. To control the actual output, these other two parts are highly relevant.

Comment: @derhass: Yes, I am looking at the _shader output values directly_. I have edited my question.

Comment: Then you need to show your shader

Comment: How do you retrieve the colors? Using a QRenderCapture? Maybe you could rewrite your question a bit to make everything clearer. E.g. your sentence "I need 32 bit color because I'm working on a offscreen renderer" doesn't make sense - the reason why you need 32 bit colors is because you want point snapping. Other than that I agree with @derhass that we need so your shader, as well.

Comment: Yes, I am using `QRenderCapture` as it is written in your example.

My shader is really simple: `gl_VertexID` is transformed to `vec4` color.

Comment: I'm still not really sure what exactly you want to achieve. What is the computation doing in your shader? That is your fragment shader? If I understand correctly: you want to retrieve the vertex' ID from the offscreen rendered image to be able to tell "at position (x, y) we rendered vertex with ID XXX", right? If yes, why don't you abuse the alpha channel as well, and not only the RGB channels? You could store another 8 bit in there and later get the alpha from the QImage.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. This computations transforms vertex ID to a unique color (RGB, without alpha channel). I cannot use alpha channel because created `QImage`'s alpha channel is always set to `1.000` no matter what I do.

Comment: But in your fragment shader you set the alpha channel to 1. It might be that you still have to adjust the `QImage`'s internal format to an alpha-supporting one.

Comment: `QRenderCaptureReply` returns `QImage` which does not have an alpha channel. `hasAlphaChannel()` returns `False`.